# OpenCV error: Assertion failed (mask.size == src1.size) in binary_op

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I am trying to place a png image image of a hat over the head of a webcam 
feed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Load the overlay image: hat.png
imghat = cv2.imread('hat2.png', -1)

print imghat is None

# Create the mask for the hat
imghatGray = cv2.cvtColor(imghat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imwrite("imghatGray.png", imghatGray)

ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imghatGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv2.imwrite("orig_mask.png", orig_mask)

# Create the inverted mask for the hat
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)
#cv2.imwrite("orig_mask_inv.png", orig_mask_inv)

# Convert hat image to BGR
# and save the original image size (used later when re-sizing the image)
imghat = imghat[:,:,0:3]
origHatHeight, origHatWidth = imghat.shape[:2]

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print "x : %d , y : %d, w: %d, h: %d " %(x,y,w,h)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x-15,y-h), (x+w+15, y), (255,255,0), 2)

        hatWidth = w
        hatHeight = hatWidth * origHatHeight / origHatWidth

            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        # Center the hat
        x1 = x - 15
        y1 = y - h
        x2 = x1 + w + 30
        y2 = y1 + h

        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)

        # Check for clipping
        if x1 < 0:
            x1 = 0
        if y1 < 0:
            y1 = 0
        if x2 > 640:
            x2 = w
        if y2 > 360:
            y2 = h


        print "x1: %d , y1 : %d, x2: %d, y2: %d " %(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        # Re-calculate the width and height of the hat image
        hatWidth = x2 - x1
        hatHeight = y2 - y1

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), (x2, y2), (255,255,0), 2)
        print "hatWidth: %d, hatHeight: %d" %(hatWidth, hatHeight)      
        # Re-size the original image and the masks to the hat sizes
        # calcualted above
        hat = cv2.resize(imghat, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # take ROI for hat from background equal to size of hat image
        roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        # roi_bg contains the original image only where the hat is not
        # in the region that is the size of the hat.
        roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

        # roi_fg contains the image of the hat only where the hat is
        roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(hat,hat,mask = mask)

        # join the roi_bg and roi_fg
        dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

        # place the joined image, saved to dst back over the original image
        roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst

        break



    # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)


        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I execute the program, the camera opens and closes abruptly. The error  shown is in the below line -

**roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask = mask_inv)**

Comment: Can you post the whole error traceback?

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mask.size == src1.size) in binary_op, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1036
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_head.py", line 83, in <module>
    roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
cv2.error: /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1036: error: (-215) mask.size == src1.size in function binary_op

Comment: Check if size of your image captured from camera and the one you are making mask form is same. I had same error, turned out it was default capturing resolution of camera, every time i change camera i get this error. I fixed resolution of camera while capturing and this error is no more. hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score 2):

The error is

```
Assertion failed (mask.size == src1.size)
```

i.e. The size of the mask image does't match the size of the source image that you're doing the bitwise_and on

The source image is your ROI

```
roi = roi_color[ y1:y2, x1:x2 ]
```

which looks like `y2-y1` x `x2-x1`

The mask size is

```
mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

which looks like `hatWidth` x `hatHeight` i.e. `(x2-x1)` x `(y2-y1)`
unless the parentheses do something to invert the order of the width and height - I'm not a Python guru but this seems unlikely.

Comment: From what I have read, the x and y co-ordinates are backwards while selecting an ROI.

Comment: the error is that the ROi and mask are not the same size. Try printing the size of the two before calling bit wise and to see which is the correct soze