# OpenCV Masking Image - error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to subtract the background from an image using a mask and OpenCV's bitwise_and. However, I get the following error:

> error:
>   C:\ci\opencv_1512684736357\work\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:241:
>   error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in
>   function cv::binary_op

My code looks like this:

```
mask = get_mask() #function that returns a mask (boolean)

#conversion of the mask
mask = mask.astype('int')
mask[mask == 0] = 255
mask[mask == 1] = 0

fg_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

A question here on StackOverflow ([OpenCV Python Error: error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019023/opencv-python-error-error-215-mtype-cv-8u-mtype-cv-8s-mask-s)) that addresses the same error indicates an issue with a potential shape mismatch. However, checking both the shape of my mask and my image it appears to me that they match, yielding:

```
mask.shape
OUT: (100, 83)

img.shape
OUT: (100, 83, 3)
```

I am using Python v3 and OpenCV v2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not a shape mismatch... it is failing in the first part of the assert:

> mtype == 0 || mtype == 1

It says that the type of the mask (`mtype`) should be either 0 or 1, i.e. `CV_8U` and `CV_8S` respectively.

You are using:

```
mask = mask.astype('int')
```

That means type `CV_32S` or 4 in the enum value.

Solution:

You can use `np.uint8` or `np.int8` assuming that you have done `import numpy as np`