# i am learning python so wrote this small code to add 2 images with ROI but it is showing me error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have wrote a code which i copied from internet while learning open cv but when i run this code it is showing me some errors i don't know how to fix it

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load two images
img1 = cv2.imread('car.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('coca cola.png')

# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]

# Now create a mask of logo and create its inverse mask also
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)

# Put logo in ROI and modify the main image
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst

cv2.imshow('res',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it is showing me this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Python codes/put one
> image on other.py", line 18, in <module>
>     img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv) cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3)
> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:241:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) &&
> _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

Comment: 8U or 8S looks like 8 bit unsigned or signed. probably wrong/unsupported image type in input. Those libs aren't as good as standard ones when it comes to error messages ...

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019023/opencv-python-error-error-215-mtype-cv-8u-mtype-cv-8s-mask-s

Comment: The types here all look fine, I would check the size of your images and masks and be sure it's all good. Is it possible that your coca cola image is larger than your car image?